# Time Limit Exceeded on Leetcode problem Number of Boomerangs

Tags: python

I'm working on Leetcode problem "[Number of Boomerangs](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-boomerangs/)".

The python code I wrote is

```
def numberOfBoomerangs(self, points):
        """
        :type points: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        import numpy as np
        count = 0
        no_of_points = len(points)
        points = np.array(points)
        for ind_c in range(no_of_points):
            dis_array = np.zeros((no_of_points))
            for ind_n in range(no_of_points):
                dis_array[ind_n] = np.linalg.norm(points[ind_c] - points[ind_n])
            dis_set = set(dis_array)
            if len(dis_set) != len(dis_array):
                for item in dis_set:
                    validKeys = np.in1d(dis_array, item)
                    validKeys[ind_c] = False
                    slice_length = len(dis_array[validKeys])
                    if slice_length > 1:
                        count += slice_length * (slice_length - 1)
        return count
```

However, this piece of code suffers from Time Limit Exceeded problem which I have no idea how to handle.

Can this piece of code still be improved? Should I try some other strategies?

Comment: Are you sure using numpy is allowed? Also, what is your algorithm? Whats its time complexity?

Comment: Looking at the code the time complexity is around O(no_of_points^2 + n)